# Configuring Navigation with Jekyll Liquid

Tags: html, menu, navigation, jekyll, liquid

I'm new to this.

I'm trying to achieve the opposite of this: http://christianspecht.de/2014/06/18/building-a-pseudo-dynamic-tree-menu-with-jekyll/ where rather than adding a link it would remove a link.

So for example say I have three pages (page 1, page 2, and page 3). When on page 2, show links to all three pages but when on page 1 or on page 3 only show links to the current page and to page 2.

What's the best/simplest way to go about this?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is quite difficult to understand can you explain a little more what is your navigation concept ?

Comment: I have written the blog post which you linked in your question, but I don't understand your question either. It rather sounds to me like you want to implement "next page/previous page" links...if yes, then I don't understand the connection to my blog post.